# IDA fails to load Symbols from EXE on Linux

Tags: ida, symbols

When I try to load a Portable Executable in IDA Pro 6.6 it can't resolve the Symbols. I have hooked it to a `win32_remote.exe`. It keeps saying `E_PDB_NOT_FOUND`.

I even have WinDBG installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common issue is missing `symsrv.dll`. Please make sure you have it on the remote machine and that `win32_remote.exe` can find it.

You can also append `-z10000` to the command line in order to get more output from the MS-DIA libraries.

Thanks to HexRays for this answer.

Comment: awesome, but what is the exact meaning of that switch (`-z`)? Is that some debug level of a kind?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: it's actually documented

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: it would still be better to include it here. But it was a mere suggestion. No offense intended.